# Is it possible to have two mouseovers at once?

Tags: javascript, mouseover

I was wondering if it was possible to mouseover two things at once.
I have a white background and code that creates black splatters where the mouse trails. I wanted to know if it was possible to add white text to the center that could only be seen after mousing over with the black.
I added what I have so far below.

I'm new to this so I would appreciate any help I could get! Thank you so much.

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById("my-canvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

// this section is the code for the trailing black splatters when you move the mouse
let atoms = [];

canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e){
    for (let i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        atoms.push(new Atom(e.x, e.y));    
    }
});

const animate = () => {
    atoms.forEach((atom, index) => {
        atom.draw();
        atom.updateSpeed();
        atom.updateSize();

        if (atom.radius < 0.3){
            atoms.splice(index, 1);
        }
    })
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
} 

animate();

class Atom{
    constructor(x,y){
        this.x = x
        this.y = y
        this.radius = Math.random() * 8 + 2;
        this.speedX = Math.random() * 4 - 2; // -2+2
        this.speedY = Math.random() * 4 - 2; // -2+2
    }
    updateSpeed(){
        this.x += this.speedX;
        this.y += this.speedY;

    }

    updateSize(){
        this.radius-= 0.1;
    }
    draw(){
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, this.radius, 0, Math.PI*2);
        ctx.fill();
    }
}

// this section is for mouseover text that says "there's always more to see"
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

</head>
<body>
    <h1 style = "color: black;"> RENA </h1>
    <canvas  id="my-canvas"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you mean? If so you don't need two mouseovers, just add some white text that is positioned above your "canvas" element, it will be invisible due to the background being white. When the black splatters appear, the white text gets revealed.

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById("my-canvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

// this section is the code for the trailing black splatters when you move the mouse
let atoms = [];

canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e){
    for (let i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        atoms.push(new Atom(e.x, e.y));    
    }
});

const animate = () => {
    atoms.forEach((atom, index) => {
        atom.draw();
        atom.updateSpeed();
        atom.updateSize();

        if (atom.radius < 0.3){
            atoms.splice(index, 1);
        }
    })
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
} 

animate();

class Atom{
    constructor(x,y){
        this.x = x
        this.y = y
        this.radius = Math.random() * 8 + 2;
        this.speedX = Math.random() * 4 - 2; // -2+2
        this.speedY = Math.random() * 4 - 2; // -2+2
    }
    updateSpeed(){
        this.x += this.speedX;
        this.y += this.speedY;

    }

    updateSize(){
        this.radius-= 0.1;
    }
    draw(){
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, this.radius, 0, Math.PI*2);
        ctx.fill();
    }
}

// this section is for mouseover text that says "there's always more to see"
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

</head>
<body>
    <h1 style = "color: black;"> RENA </h1>
<!-- ///// ADDED TEXT BENEATH BLACK TEXT //// -->
<span style = "color: white; z-index: 10; margin-top: 70px; position: absolute;"><h2>There's always more to see</h2></span>
    <canvas  id="my-canvas">

</canvas>
</body>
</html>
```